# Can I manage the photos that are pulled from Instagram before they are uploaded?

Tags: wp-admin, uploads

I'm building a WordPress website and I want to pull instagram photos with a certain hashtag and upload them to my site. My concern is that there's always the risk of the photos being inappropriate. Is there a way to review these pulled photos via my WP admin panel (or using something else) to manually check if the photos are safe for work and then upload them?

Comment: WordPress does not have a feature for pulling Instagram photos. Are you using a plugin?

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking of using 10web but I don't want the images to be immediately uploaded because instagram has a ton of nsfw content.

Comment: You will need to direct this question to the developers of any plugins you're considering. It would be up to them to implement this feature, and third party plugins are off topic here.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help!